# Does a const getter returning a modifiable reference in C++ make sense?

Tags: c++, getter

is the following getter make sense?

```cpp
MyType& MyClass::getMyType() const { return mMyType; }
```

I don't modify `this` but I give access to someone else to modify it.
Is it something to avoid?

My IDE generate getter the following way:

```cpp
MyType       & MyClass::getMyType()       { return mMyType; }
MyType const & MyClass::getMyType() const { return mMyType; }
```

is it better? I don't need the const version

Comment: Well if `mMyType` was declared `mutable` I don't think this would be an issue. You can't even compile yours otherwise as the qualifiers of `this` would be discarded

Comment: Did you try to compile your version?

Comment: Why would I provide the `MyType const & MyClass::getMyType() const { return mMyType; }` it's the same code has `MyType & MyClass::getMyType() { return mMyType; }` and I can always const the return value of `MyType & MyClass::getMyType() { return mMyType; }`

Comment: @Fractale What if you want to bind to a `const &` of your object, and access `mMyType`. You can't do that with `non const-qualified` functions. Try iterating through a `const std::map`, while accessing its members via `operator[]`. You can't since `operator[]` is not const-qualified

Comment: `const` (on the right side) doesn't only mean "I don't modify the object"? Does it also mean, I don't give the right to others too, I will only return const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` is transitive. If it were any other way it would be meaningless.

The general case for your version isn't legal C++, because in a `const` method all the data members are treaded as `const`. To be able to hand out `mMyType` like that it would have to be qualified as `mutable`.

> I don't need the const version

You need it if you ever hold const references to `MyClass`, e.g. if they are ever elements of a `std::set` or keys of a `std::map`, or you want to write a function that can be called with either lvalues or rvalues.

However the easier option is to just make `mMyType` public, because a public mutable getter lets anyone do whatever they want.

```
MyClass myClass;
myClass.getMyType() = MyType(args...); // It's a setter too!
```

Comment: const can be transitive. but const it isn't always transitive. Whether it is transitive is up to the design of the class.

Comment: @eerorika I explain that in more detail in the following paragraph. sub-objects of a `const` object are `const` unless `mutable`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it doesn't.

```
MyType       & MyClass::getMyType()       { return mMyType; }
MyType const & MyClass::getMyType() const { return mMyType; }
```

broke the encapsulation.

The encapsulation means that if you want to modify a data member, you must call explicitly a function, such as a setter, which allows you to do the modification. However, in your code, `obj.getMyType()` can or can't modify the data member. So for me it's just like setting `mMyType` as public.

I won't touch the const version `getMyType()` but I will remove the non-const version and add some new functions, such as `void setMember1OfMyType(...)`, `void setMember2OfMyType(...)` etc.

Comment: you are right about broken encapsulation. but if MyType is a class with a lot of member functions will you make a lot of setters to call these functions?

Comment: `void setMember1OfMyType(...)` is still unencapsulated. `void doMyClassThing(...) // modifies mMyType` is encapsulation

Comment: @Fractale  In fact, your question is about code design. If `MyType` contains lots of data members, well, you should stop thinking about how to make a proper setter, you should consider if it's better to make a friend-relational classes, or to use a singleton pattern, etc.

Comment: @Fractale In a word, what you are doing here is simple: modify the data members of an object in a class. So first of all, you should ask yourself: "why do I need to do so especially the object contains lots of data members". If so, I would suggest you making them friend.

Comment: @Caleth hmm, I don't think so. I would call `mMyType.setter` in `void setMember1OfMyType(...)`.

Comment: @Yves my point is that just exposing the transitive members of `mMyType` is also not encapsulation. You expose *behaviour*, which might involve modifications to state

Answer (score 0):

> is the following getter make sense?
>
> ```
> MyType& MyClass::getMyType() const { return mMyType; }
> ```

It can make sense. It doesn't make sense necessarily.

> Is it something to avoid?

Often, yes. But not always.

> ```
> MyType       & MyClass::getMyType()       { return mMyType; }
> MyType const & MyClass::getMyType() const { return mMyType; }
> ```
>
> is it better?

Often, yes. But not always

It boils down to what the function does. If you return reference to a member, then const should be transitive and the constness of the reference should match the constness of `*this`. You'll find that your suggested getter would be ill-formed in this case. However, if you think you would need to provide a non-const reference getter, then consider making the member public instead.

If the function represents indirection, then constness of the reference and constness of `*this` should be separate.

Transitive const is generally easier to understand while non-transitive const is a bit more error prone and harder for beginners to understand.

Answer (score 0):

My general advice would be that, instead of providing a getter that returns a reference, make the field public. You achieve the same thing and it's cleaner.